# ¿Cómo evitar que queden pestañas abiertas al cerrar sesión en una de ellas?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo un sistema hecho con PHP y JQuery el cual se encarga de recibir datos en un formulario para montarlos en un PDF. Todo funciona perfectamente.
Manejo el login de los usuarios a través de un modal y todo está como debe ser.
El problema está cuando el usuario sale de la sesión.
La misma se destruye de manera perfecta, pero cuando hay varias pestañas abiertas, las demás quedan abiertas y no sé cómo activar en ellas una función que abra el modal en cada una de ellas para así evitar que puedan, por ejemplo, rellenar un formulario sin estar logueados.
Me explico mejor: abrí 2 pestañas de mi página. En una tengo el formulario y en la otra la página index. De repente me olvidé de cerrar la pestaña y simplemente opté por darle clic a mi botón de logout. Cuando reviso y entro a la página del formulario, puedo seguir añadiendo información y guárdandola como si aún estuviera mi sesión activa.
Lo que quiero es que al hacer logout en una pestaña, automáticamente el modal que tengo para realizar el loggin se muestre al usuario sin que se deba recargar la página manualmente, para que así cuando se revisen las demás pestañas deba loggearse o sólo verá el modal.

Comment: En cada página del sitio tendría que estar corriendo un llamado periódico que valide si la sesión sigue activa (usando ajax). Sin código en la pregunta, es todo lo que se puede hacer.

Comment: Es decir, ¿Coloco una función que verifique casa cierto tiempo que pa variable de sesión esté activa dentro del codigo php donde la recibo?

Comment: Existe una variable llamada `$_SESSION` en `PHP` la cual se encarga de almacenar la sesion del usuario, simplemente debes comprobar del lado de PHP al hacer cualquier otro tipo de accion dentro de las otras paginas de que si la sesion aun existe, es decir, pedirle a `PHP` mediante `ajax` que te devuelva `true` o `false` dependiendo de si hay una sesion iniciada o no, esto servira para todas las pestañas en las que tuvieses una sesion, puesto que si encuentras que no hay una sesion abierta simplemente rediriges a la persona al login de nuevo.

Comment: Cuando me refiero a "cualquier otro tipo de accion" puede ser por ejemplo como navegar entre distintos menus de la pagina o simplemente darle click a un boton o una imagen, asi es como funciona la plataforma de mi universidad por ejemplo.

Comment: Con local storage de javascript o cookies dentro de php puedes lograrlo.

Comment: Hola Brayan. Tu pregunta está respondida en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434993/c%c3%b3mo-cerrar-sesi%c3%b3n-autom%c3%a1ticamente-en-todas-las-pesta%c3%b1as-abiertas-cuando-el-usu/436500#436500