# ¿Cómo cerrar sesión automáticamente en todas las pestañas abiertas cuando el usuario cierra sesión solo en una de ellas?

Tags: laravel, login, session, sesiones

estoy aprendiendo Laravel 8 y me encanta. Realicé toda la autenticación de usuarios con Auth, y establecí rutas para que el usuario que no está logeado no pueda accederlas y todo esto funciona genial. Ahora bien, el usuario puede tener varias páginas abiertas en el navegador, pero luego de que realiza el logout en una de ellas automáticamente lo redirige a la vista de inicio del sitio web (/), el problema es que las otras páginas quedan con el usuario logeado y dentro de vistas propias del perfil de usuario y al querer accederlas sale el error "419 page expired" (y es lógico porque también invalido y regenero un nuevo token), solamente al refrescarlas manualmente aparece que el usuario ya no está logeado. Necesitaría saber como hacer para que todas las páginas abiertas se refresquen automáticamente al hacer logout, pienso que podría realizarse con JSON, pero no he encontrado mucho al respecto. Muchas gracias desde ya.

Código del LoginController.php

```
{
    Auth::logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerateToken(); //probada-cumple esta función generando un nuevo TOKEN
    return redirect('/');  

}
```

Comment: has investigado algo al respecto o esta pregunta constituye el inicio de tu investigación?

Comment: lo que he encontrado hasta ahora es que a muchos no les cierra la sesión en todas las paginas que tienen abiertas o temas parecidos, pero concretamente en mi sistema si funciona bien el cierre de session. Ademas, maneja solo una sesión, solamente que no encuentro sobre mi tema en particular. En el manual de Laravel solo indica como se puede cerrar sesión en diferentes dispositivos, pero no es lo que busco aquí.

Comment: Lo que debieras hacer, Ceci, es manejar un sistema de mensajes muy sencillo entre tabs. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428453/usuario-activo-sin-importar-en-que-pesta%c3%b1a-del-navegador-este/428874#428874) sugerí algunas maneras para mantener sincronizado el TTL del usuario. En tu caso es algo parecido. La ventana que recibe la respuesta del logout le avisa a las demás

Comment: @ffflabs probaré con lo que me pasaste

Comment: @ffflabs pude hacerlo! de las opciones que me sugeriste utilicé los eventos LocalStorage. Precisamente el evento "storage" marca si hubo un cambio en el objeto localStorage, y además utilicé un Listener para captar este evento y la comunicación entre pestañas funcionó muy bien. Ahora solo estoy puliendo el tema de recargar todas las pestañas al cerrar la sesión en una de estas, por ejemplo Chrome recarga la página pero no como si fuera con F5, no hace un hard-refresh, pero en Firefox anda genial, seguiré viendo que hacer para solucionarlo. Gracias por guiarme!!

Comment: Y será necesario recargar? A lo mejor es más inmediato mandarlo a la pantalla de login para ahorrar un request. En todo caso, cómo estás haciendo esa recarga? Si estás en Vue, puede que te funcione usando `this.$router.go()`

Comment: También me falta hacer lo mismo para cuando la sesión expire por el tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Bien, lo solucioné de esta manera:

En el UsuarioController.php

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->regenerateToken();
    return redirect('login');  
}
```

Y como tengo el layaout: app.blade.php que utilizo en todas las vistas, añadí el script donde utilicé el evento "storage" que marca si hubo un cambio en el objeto localStorage, utilizando el Listener para captar este evento. Gracias a esto, la comunicación entre pestañas funciona al cerrar sesión en solo una de ellas enviando al usuario a la vista del Login en el resto. También actualiza todas las pestañas abiertas si el usuario solo se logueo en alguna de ellas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function storageChange (event) {
      if(localStorage.logeado=="false"){
         window.location.replace("/login"); //si el uuario hizo logout
      }else
         window.location.reload(true); //si el usuario se logueo
      }

    window.addEventListener('storage', storageChange, false)

</script>
```

Y por ultimo, en este mismo layaout, el código para cuando el usuario cierra sesión manualmente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.localStorage.setItem('logeado', true);</script>
```

...

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick ="window.localStorage.setItem('logeado', false); event.preventDefault();
document.getElementById('logout-form').submit(); ">{{ __('Cerrar Sesión') }}
</a>
```

Destaco en esta parte el siguiente codigo:
window.localStorage.setItem('logeado', false)